# How to load authenticated users's entity model from Spring Data JPA using Spring security to use in other JPA Repositories?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security

I have a `UserEntity` model and corresponding `UserRepository.` Similarly I have `BookEntity` model and `BookRepository`. Book has `@ManyToOne` relation with User.

So in Book entity, there is a field that maps to User entity's id as FK using `@ManyToOne` annotation. When I want to retrieve list of books based on a User, I call the method `List<BookEntity> findByUser(UserEntity user);` from `BookRepository`, using Spring Data JPA.

I can load the current authenticated user with help of Spring security but this gives me a `UserDetails` object. What I need is `UserEntity` object so that I can pass it to `BookRepository` methods.

Right now, what am doing is calling `Optional<UserEntity> findByUsername(String username);` from `UserRepository` to get `UserEntity` and to do this, I'm getting the username from `UserDetails` instance provided by Spring security. And then passing this `UserEntity` model to `BookRepository` methods.

I want to know if this the right way to load `UserEntity` model for passing into `BookRepository` or is there any other way to do so? If not, am I mapping Books to User incorrectly?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your BookRepository do something like

```
@Query("FROM Book b where b.user.userName = :userName")
List<Book> findBooksForUser(@Param("userName") String userName);
```

You can get current user username in a controller like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getBooks(Authentication authentication) {
  if(authentication != null){
    //Call bookRepo.findBooksForUser(authentication.getName())
  }

  ....
}
```

Comment: The field in my Book class is a long type which maps to userId. Spring security gives me a username. Hence I require UserEntity instance.

Comment: With @ManyToOne, JPA creates an association and hence the DSL will reslove to correct join between Book and User and filter records on username.

Comment: Something like select * from books b join users u on u.id = b.user_id where u.username = 'abc';